# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when making a program to upload image to firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am making a simple program to upload images and files to firebase cloud. I am still somewhat a novice at web-apps, so I don't understand what the error is caused by. When I save, there are no errors in code. However when I compile it, the page doesn't load and it gives me one error in console:

core.js:24134 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24134)

at core.js:24145

at Array.forEach ()

at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24145)

at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:24242)

at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:27786)

at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:28024)

at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)

at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:84)

at Object.0 (main.ts:12)

I am not good at debugging this stuff, so all help is appreciated.

```
    //HTML: 
    
    <div class="choose_file">
         <span><ion-icon name="cloud-upload-outline"></ion-icon>Upload</span>
         <input name="Select File" type="file" (change)='uploadFile($event)'/>
    </div>
    
    //Typescript:
    
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tab1',
      templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
    })
    export class Tab1Page {
    
      constructor( private storage: AngularFireStorage) {}
    
        uploadFile(event) {
          const file = event.target.files[0];
          var filePath = "test-image";
    
          const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
          var task = fileRef.put(file);
        }
      }
    
    //App Routing Module TS:
    
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
    
    import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
    import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularFireStorage
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Nothing in this code attempts to access the 'id' property of anything. Is there more code you can show us? This error will be related to whatever is trying to access something['id'] or something.id so look for place where that happens in your code.

Comment: Debugging is crucial to programming! You need to see if you can get this error in your development environment after running `ionic serve` so that your typescript source maps will point you to the right line of code throwing the error. The code you provided doesn't show us anything useful.

Comment: @Steve I am using a firebase app ID could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe. The best advice I can give you is that you need to look for an array you are looping through. In that array you are accessing the id of something that is undefined. Without the relevant code I can't do any more.